# Do you earn crates faster in ranked games or in casual ones?

Tags: rocket-league

Do you earn crates faster in ranked matches, or do you get them faster in casual games?

Comment: AFAIK it's exactly the same

Comment: From recent experience, it would seem you can only get a crate every 12 hours or so, and it doesn't matter where you play. Winning seems to have a strong correlation to getting a crate, but if you lose enough one will also drop.

Answer (score 2):

Competitive would only have an edge because of the difficulty of leaving the match compared to casual.

Provided you don't leave often though, they should be equal.